# Can anyone help me with this struct/pointer issue?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
strcpy((*pointeur).caractere, x);
```

I use `strcpy` to copy the value of `x` to `(*pointeur).caractere` and I define the struct

```
typedef struct cle{
    char caractere;
    int compteur;
    struct cle *suivant;
}cle_t;
```

and declare the pointer

```
cle_t *pointeur;
```

but the compiler told me that

> "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'"

and

> "initializing argument 1 of `char* strcpy(char*, const char*)' "

I can't understand what goes wrong...
Thank you all guys~

Comment: The `str*()` family of functions works on character **arrays**. Arrays of characters carrying a `'\0'` as last element are commonly called strings.

Comment: oh, thanks for reminding that...i understand now...

Answer (score 2):

*Salut* !

`caractere` is a character, and `strcpy` works with strings. There are two solutions, according to what you want to do (with your identifiers, I guess you are rather in the fist case).

- If `x` is a `char`, use `pointeur->caractere = x` (no need to `strcpy` to copy characters).
- If `x` is a `char*` or a `char[]`, declare `caractere` as a string with a sufficient length (ie with an array of `char` or a pointer to `char` dynamically allocated), and then you can call `strcpy`.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Thanks for your comment; I'm sorry. I'll correct it.

Comment: No reason to be sorry. De rien.

Comment: but, when I change the line to `pointeur->caractere = x` cause I had defined `char x = 'a'`, but it doesn't work neither...

Comment: it's a compilation error: invalid conversion from `char*` to `char`.....the error becomes reverse....

Comment: @Bob Zhen: Are you sure `pointeur->caractere` and `x` are both `char` type? Otherwise, paste your source code.

Comment: `void insertion_tete(cle_t *ptete, char *x, int compteur){
  cle_t *pointeur;
  pointeur = (cle_t *)malloc(sizeof(cle_t));
  //strcpy(pointeur->caractere, x);
  printf("%c", x);
  //strcpy((*pointeur).caractere, x);
  pointeur->caractere = x;
  pointeur->compteur = compteur;
  pointeur->suivant = NULL;
  pointeur->suivant = ptete->suivant;
  ptete->suivant = pointeur;
}`

Comment: yes, i'm sure that, this is a function to insert a value(contains a char, an int and a pointer) into the head of a list...

Comment: @BobZhen: `x` is a `char*`, not a `char`. If it is really a character, you have to dereference it: `pointeur->caractere = *x`.

Comment: @Kirilenko it works now, thank you very much...i'm not very good at C, especially in the area of pointer, please forgive me those little errors...bonne journée~

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy((*pointeur).caractere, x);
```

This will work fine but `caractere` should be a `char *`or `char[]`

here is the declaration of `strcpy()`

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

Also note that if you are creating `caractere` as a `char*` then make sure to allocate memory for this other wise using `strcpy()` will give `undefined behaviour` or may lead to `seg fault`

One more thing : If you are making a pointer to `struct` then you can directly use `->` operator to access the data members

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes, this works fine, but i just want to use char, if i use char* or char[], that's another stuff to work...thank you anyway....

Answer (score 0):

1- syntax:
You have a pointer to a struct and then access its fields: this case is so common that C provides ''syntactic honey'' (du ''miel syntaxique''; en fait l'expression réelle est ''syntactic sugar'', je plaisante):

```
(p_struct*).field
// -->
p_struct->field
```

In your case:

```
strcpy((*pointeur).caractere, x);
// -->
strcpy(pointeur->caractere);
```

Use this form not only because it's nicer, but because everyone uses the arrow, so the meaning is more obvious.

2- `strcpy` copies strings, not characters. Strings are character arrays, with a `0` at the end, or pointers to them. So, if you want to use strcpy, you need either to replace the field `caractere` with a field `chaine` holding a string, or make a string on the fly from `caractere` before passing it to `strcpy`. But if you only want to copy the char, just copy it with `=`.

3- Beware of the misleading term "character". A C `char` actually is just a byte (moreover, either signed or not depending on your platform). For universal text, that is anything but ASCII, an actual character (in the evryday, linguistic, or programming sense) may be represented with one or more codes, each taking one or more bytes (C `char`s). (See [UCS](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS) & [Unicode](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) on wikipedia.)